# Rails: how do you tell cron to execute a controller method?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model-view-controller, cron, rake

So a bunch of mailing methods in Article controller, that mix different types of articles with different users. All work fine when called from somewhere within Rails. But they need to be executed during the week by cron. What goes in place of "xxxx" in the rake file to tell it to execute the "10_am_action" method in the Article controller?

articles_controller.rb:

```
def 10_am_action
  [sends the right e-mails to the right users]
end
```

Cron:

```
0 10 * * 0  cd /data/website/current && RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake emails:10_am
```

emails.rake:

```
namespace :briefings do

desc "10 am e-mails"
task :10_am => :environment do
    xxxxxx
end

end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't because controllers are bound to HTTP.

However, you can refactor your code and extract the email sending logic to a mailer, and call that mailer from both your controller and your rake task.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I'll just bung it in the rake task file for now. But to keep it all tidy, where are you supposed to put code that can be executed either by a controller or by a rake task?

Comment: You could add a "service" object, also see Hexagonal Architecture: http://www.confreaks.com/videos/977-goruco2012-hexagonal-rails